# What is the return type for an Event in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like know what's the default return type for an Event: somebody says Event has not return type; others says Event has return type.
Thanks.

Comment: its void...you can see where you define event.....

Comment: Event is object and object doesn't return anything, I think you're asking about event handler..!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on the type of the delegate you declare the event with. "Typical" events are declared with a delegate of type `EventHandler` or `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` which returns `void`, but nothing forbids declaring an event with a different type of delegate... if not the Principle Of Least Surprise (POLS).

"Typical":

```
public event EventHandler MyVoidEvent;
```

"Custom":

```
public delegate bool MyBoolDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
public event MyBoolDelegate MyBoolEvent;
```

Normally you would put "return values" in the `EventArgs` object, that's why events don't *need* to return values... but they can if they're told to.

Comment: Good answer. With events, usually, it is intended that many different agents could "subscribe" to the same event, each of them calling the (implicit) `add` accessor of the event. The underlying delegate field therefore contains a multicast delegate. Then multicast delegates with return types different from `void` work by returning the output from the ***last*** method on the invocation list of that multicast delegate. That is hardly useful in the context of events. So I would strongly advice the asker not to declare events whose delegate type returns anything.

Answer (score 8):

By default most event handlers return void, however, it is possible for handlers to return values.

You can refer this article for further reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2008/11/27/event-handlers-returning-values.aspx

Comment: Note the difference between an `event` and an `EventHandler`